# Shrinking workspace rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, workspace

How do I shrink the workspace rectangle (with a form, preferably)?
I want to achieve a similar effect like the [Windows Vista Sidebar](http://computrgeek.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/vista-sidebar.jpg), [Google Desktop](http://www.nela.in/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/google-desktop_2.jpg), [Longhorn sidebar](http://www.thoosje.com/Images/Longhorn-sidebar-scrn.jpg) or [LongBar](http://longbar.codeplex.com/).
I am not sure if it matters, but I'd like to eat space from the bottom.

Comment: The source code is available for LongBar at the link you posted. You could look through that to figure out how they're doing it if you want to replicate that in your own application.

Comment: Obviously I thought about that, but I couldn't find it. I actually find it very hard to understand someone else's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx) is a C# example.